# Allow the main header to be underlined when the sub header is clicked

Tags: jquery, navigation

```
<div id=wrapDesktopNavBar>   
    <ul class="desktopNavBar">  
    <li><a id="firstLevel" href="#">header 1</a></li>  
    <li><a id="firstLevel" href="#">header 2</a>  
        <ul>   
        <li><a id="secondLevel" href="#">1st sub header under header 2</a>  
        <li><a id="secondLevel" href="#">2nd sub header under header 2</a>  
        <li><a id="secondLevel" href="#">3rd sub header under header 2</a>  
            </ul>  
    <li><a id="firstLevel" href="#">header 3</a></li>
```

and so on

```
$(function(){
$('.desktopNavBar a').bind('click', function(e){
    $('.desktopNavBar a.current').removeClass('current');
    $(this.hash).show();
    $(this).addClass('current');

    e.preventDefault();

}).filter('a:first').click();
});
```

I have a class called "current" which simply underlines the header when it's being clicked. I want to allow the main header to be underlined when the sub header is being clicked. I've tried `$(this).parent('a').addClass('current');` but it doesn't work.

Comment: i can help you if you will paste also the html source.

Comment: <div id=wrapDesktopNavBar>
   <ul class="desktopNavBar">
 <li><a id="firstLevel" href="#">header 1</a></li>
 <li><a id="firstLevel" href="#">header 2</a>
     <ul>
  <li><a id="secondLevel" href="#">sub header 1</a>
  <li><a id="secondLevel" href="#">sub header 2</a>
  <li><a id="secondLevel" href="#">sub header 3</a>
            </ul>
 <li><a id="firstLevel" href="#">header 3</a></li>

Comment: you can edit ur question.

Comment: You have invalid HTML markup **id attributes should be unique in a HTML page** use classes instead

Comment: Not very sure what you mean! but thanks for answering!

Comment: I have added the html codes above! This is my first time using so i'm not very sure how to indent the html codes properly. Everything appears to be on the left.

Comment: you have multiple elements with the same ids "firstLevel" and "secondLevel", that is not valid in HTML, you cannot repeat ids, use classes instead

Comment: right now, my .addClass('current') works when the user clicks on the headers. but, it only underlines my sub-headers. i want the header to be be underlined when its sub header is clicked.

Comment: See my answer below, that will help you style the header but I'm telling you that in no circumstances you can repeat an id attribute in a HTML page, you need to use classes instead, you can apply the same class for multiple elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Use this selector instead, no need for extra classes

```
$(this).closest('.desktopNavBar > li').find('a:first').addClass('current');
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DqYQM/)**

Also make sure you [validate your HTML markup](http://validator.w3.org/check) because there are some errors in what you posted, for example some li tags are not closed

Comment: I have changed it to classes as suggested. However, when i added $(this).closest('.firstLevel').addClass('current'); to my javascript, it didn't work.
But thanks so much for your prompt reply :)

Comment: I'm not very sure if it matters but this is where i placed the suggested script
$(function(){
 
 $('.desktopNavBar a').bind('click', function(e){  
  $('.desktopNavBar .current').removeClass('current');
    $(this.hash).show();
  $(this).addClass('current');
   $(this).closest('.firstLevel').addClass('current');
   e.preventDefault();
   }).filter('a:first').click();
});

Comment: Hi Koala_dev! Thanks so much for your help! It works perfectly now.